# CDI @Obeserves with default methods

Tags: events, jakarta-ee, cdi

Maybe I'm missing something, but with Java 8 we can have default methods inside an Interface and I`m trying to modify an existing one, adding a new default method that Observes an Event and calls the old method signature at this same Interface, just to avoid code changes in legacy Beans (in this case, all @ApplicationScoped). Ex:

```
public interface A {
    public void oldMehtod(Event evt);
    default void newMethod(@Observes Event evt) {
        this.oldMehtod(Event evt);
    } 
}
```

The "newMethod" is never fired by a Bean that implements this Interface. What I`m missing? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [CDI specification](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#observer_methods), you may want to read more about it then just this quotation:

> An observer method is a non-abstract method of a managed bean class or session bean class...

Yours is not a method of a managed bean class. You will need to place that method on an actual bean class to have it discovered.

I cannot tell you exactly why you cannot have them on interfaces but I suppose it's some hard limitation. That would be good question to ask on [CDI-dev mailing list](https://lists.jboss.org/mailman/listinfo/cdi-dev).

Comment: Thank you for your time, Silliarus. Actually, I`ve already read this quotation, but the doubt reamains.

Comment: What doubt? Can you be more specific?

Comment: The original doubt, Siliarus. Since the default methods are not an abstract ones, my bean should "inherit" them from its interface or not? I considered your advice about CDI mailing list, but I was precise because the doubt still remains. Again, thanks!

Comment: @Igor Leave the `non-abstract` part of the spec sentence for now and focus on `of a managed bean class`. Interface is not a `managed bean class` it is merely one of bean *types* (unless excluded later on). See also [this chapter](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#what_classes_are_beans)